# QGIS 2.18.6 How to avoid the refresh of map when you export as image

Tags: qgis, layouts

In the version 2.18.6 if I make a layout with many thematic maps coming from the same shape, how can I avoid the refresh of the maps?

I am doing a layout with the same shapefile split in four maps with different thematic design but when I export it all maps are refreshed with only design.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you well, what you have to do is when you create the first design of the first map, you should freeze (lock) the style by checking `Lock layer for map item` and `Lock layer style for map item` for the first map. By locking the items and style of the items, you will stop refreshing the style on every change in the design.

[image]

Then you can change the design and `Add new map` for the new design and freeze (lock) the style by checking `Lock layer for map item` and `Lock layer style for map item` for the second map, and so on until you finish the four designs. Then you can export the layout to an image.

For 2.18 version, you need to use `Lock Layers` and `Lock style for Layers` which act same as `Lock layer for map item` and `Lock layer style for map item`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in th 2.18 Qgis version I have in Items Properties "lock layers" and  "lock style for layers", should they works fine?

Comment: I updated my answer considering QGIS 2.18 version.